# There is no row in position 1

Tags: vb.net

The first data I have will edit but if I move on the next it will say "There is no row in position 1" and so on. I'm using vb.net, here are my codes:

```
Private Sub ToUpdate_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Try
        con = New OleDbConnection(connectionString)
        sql = "SELECT * FROM Adds WHERE StudentID=" & student ID & ""

        da = New OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)
        ds = New DataSet
        da.Fill(ds, "Q1PT_Butil-Gulanes-Lee C-Olarte (4)")
        Call ViewData.displayData()
        txtID.Text = ds.Tables("Q1PT_Butil-Gulanes-Lee C-Olarte (4)").Rows(0).Item(0).ToString
        txtFirstName.Text = ds.Tables("Q1PT_Butil-Gulanes-Lee C-Olarte (4)").Rows(0).Item(1).ToString
        txt Mname.Text = ds.Tables("Q1PT_Butil-Gulanes-Lee C-Olarte (4)").Rows(0).Item(2).ToString
        txtMiddleI.Text = ds.Tables("Q1PT_Butil-Gulanes-Lee C-Olarte (4)").Rows(0).Item(3).ToString
        txtLastName.Text = ds.Tables("Q1PT_Butil-Gulanes-Lee C-Olarte (4)").Rows(0).Item(4).ToString
        txtGrade.Text = ds.Tables("Q1PT_Butil-Gulanes-Lee C-Olarte (4)").Rows(0).Item(5).ToString
        txtSection.Text = ds.Tables("Q1PT_Butil-Gulanes-Lee C-Olarte (4)").Rows(0).Item(6).ToString
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: you can check before use it, 
ds.Tables("Q1PT_Butil-Gulanes-Lee C-Olarte (4)").Rows.count > 0

Comment: The error message speaks for itself. If there was more than one row then there would be a row at position 1. If there's no row at position 1 then there isn't more than one row. If you expect more than one row then you need to reevaluate your expectations.

Comment: @Noob, as the documentation states, the `Fill` method is a function and it returns the number of records retrieved. That would be the logical place to get that value from.

Comment: What you're doing is a very bad way to work with data anyway.  Firstly, don't create a `DataSet` when all you need is one `DataTable`. Just create a `DataTable`. Populate that and bind it to a `BindingSource`, then bind that to your controls. You can then navigate simply by calling `MoveNext` and `MovePrevious` on the `BindingSource`. The number of rows is then irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

validate Dataset have row.

```
 Private Sub ToUpdate_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Try
            con = New OleDbConnection(connectionString)
            sql = "SELECT * FROM Adds WHERE StudentID=" & student ID & ""

            da = New OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)
            ds = New DataSet
            da.Fill(ds, "Q1PT_Butil-Gulanes-Lee C-Olarte (4)")

            if ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count = 0 then exit sub

            Call ViewData.displayData()
            txtID.Text = ds.Tables("Q1PT_Butil-Gulanes-Lee C-Olarte (4)").Rows(0).Item(0).ToString
            txtFirstName.Text = ds.Tables("Q1PT_Butil-Gulanes-Lee C-Olarte (4)").Rows(0).Item(1).ToString
            txt Mname.Text = ds.Tables("Q1PT_Butil-Gulanes-Lee C-Olarte (4)").Rows(0).Item(2).ToString
            txtMiddleI.Text = ds.Tables("Q1PT_Butil-Gulanes-Lee C-Olarte (4)").Rows(0).Item(3).ToString
            txtLastName.Text = ds.Tables("Q1PT_Butil-Gulanes-Lee C-Olarte (4)").Rows(0).Item(4).ToString
            txtGrade.Text = ds.Tables("Q1PT_Butil-Gulanes-Lee C-Olarte (4)").Rows(0).Item(5).ToString
            txtSection.Text = ds.Tables("Q1PT_Butil-Gulanes-Lee C-Olarte (4)").Rows(0).Item(6).ToString
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
```